# Can compounds (or only elements) be referred to as oxidising and reducing agents?

Tags: redox, terminology

In the reaction

$$\ce{3CuO (s) + 2NH3 (aq) <=> N2(g) + 3H2O(l) + 3Cu(s)}$$

the oxidation number of $\ce{Cu}$ goes from $+2$ in the reactant side to $0$ in the products, and so it is reduced.
The oxidation number of $\ce{O}$ is $-2$ and stays the same on both sides.

My textbook refers to $\ce{CuO}$ as the oxidising agent. Is this because the $\ce{Cu}$ in $\ce{CuO}$ is oxidised while $\ce{O}$ is neither oxidised or reduced, so overall it is an oxidising agent?

What happens for a compound $\ce{AB}$ where $\ce{A}$ gets oxidised and $\ce{B}$ gets reduced? Do I call the compound $\ce{AB}$ a reducing agent if the net change in oxidation number (between the two elements $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$) is negative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My textbook refers to $\ce{CuO}$ as the oxidising agent. Is this because the $\ce{Cu}$ in $\ce{CuO}$ is oxidised while $\ce{O}$ is neither oxidised or reduced, so overall it is an oxidising agent?

No. $\ce{CuO}$ is the oxidizing agent (the thing that causes something else to be oxidized) because the $\ce{Cu}$ is ***reduced*** (gains electrons, going from oxidation state $+2$ to $0$) in the course of oxidizing the nitrogen of $\ce{NH3}$, which loses electrons and goes from oxidation state $-3$ to $0$.

Conversely, $\ce{NH3}$ is the **reducing agent** here, because it causes something else to be reduced (here, the $\ce{Cu}$) and loses electrons in the process.

> What happens for a compound $\ce{AB}$ where $\ce A$ gets oxidised and $\ce B$ gets reduced?

If only the species $\ce{AB}$ is involved, or in the case where two of the same species $\ce A$ react to form both oxidized and reduced products:

$$
\ce{2A -> Ox + Red}
$$

the reaction is called [disproportionation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disproportionation).

> Do I call the compound $\ce{AB}$ a reducing agent if the net change in oxidation number (between the two elements $\ce A$ and $\ce B$) is negative?

Strictly in the case of a $1\!:\!1$ compound of $\ce{AB}$ on a mole basis, if the net change in oxidation number is negative, then you would call $\ce{AB}$ an ***oxidizing agent***, because it pulled electrons away from something else (it *oxidized* that other thing) in order to achieve the net negative change in oxidation number.

For $\ce{AB}$ compounds not in a $1\!:\!1$ molar ratio, a universal principle can't be stated $-$ it depends on the particulars of the mole ratio and the individual changes in oxidation number.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is the full reactants that are the oxidizing and reducing agents.  We just specify atoms for these roles as a simplifying assumption; for example, when $\ce{KMnO4}$ acts as an oxidizing agent in acid, we call the manganese the oxidizing agent because the change in manganese oxidation state from +7 to +2 accounts for the five electrons taken up by each permanganate ion during the course of reaction.  But, technically, it is the permanganate as a whole that consumes the electrons, not just the manganese.

Such a simplifying assumption is bound not to work all the time, and we may need to treat the whole compound as the oxidizing or reducing agent.  See [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/54078/balancing-by-oxidation-numbers-method-multiple-atoms/91664#91664) for an example of such a situation.