# Why isn't chlorine reduced or nitrogen oxidised in the reaction between ammonium perchlorate and aluminium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, oxidation-state

> A space shuttle’s upward thrust came from the following reaction between aluminium and ammonium perchlorate.
>
> $$\ce{10 Al + 6 NH4ClO4 → 4 Al2O3 + 2 AlCl3 + 12 H2O + 3 N2}$$
>
> Which statements about this reaction are correct?
>
> 1. Aluminium is oxidised.
> 2. Chlorine is reduced.
> 3. Nitrogen is oxidised.

I understand why aluminium is oxidized, but why are 2 and 3 wrong?

Comment: They aren't. Isn't there an "all of the above" answer?

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: Well the question as written does not require just one of them to be correct

Comment: Could it be that the question was translated and originally authors were asking about chemical substances, not elements? I'm not sure though which language would allow for such distinction.

Comment: Notice there is "which statements ...are", not "which statement .. is". The question implies more than one possibility.

Comment: @Ian Bush alright

Comment: @andselisk this is straight from Cambridge so I don't think so

Comment: @Poutnik I never noticed. This would actually make more sense. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: The English is fine - but for a question I think it could be phrased better

Comment: @Ian Bush Some questions like to play with the proper reading, what is sometimes the key to the proper answer. It trains people not to miss details.

Comment: literally everything in the a-level could be phrased better - they just don't want many of us to understand

Comment: @Jana Fair enough, I also agree that choosing all three options would be correct.

Comment: @Poutnik you're very correct in this

Comment: Since you have multiple redox reactions going on, balancing the equation by the usual redox methods is a bit tricky.  See [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/91664/17175) for one way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Here,

1. The oxidation number of chlorine in the perchlorate radical is +7 whereas, in the product side, chlorine has an oxidation number of  minus 1 in AlCl3. As the oxidation number is reduced by 8 here (gaining 8 electrons), chlorine is, indeed, reduced.
2. Nitrogen has an oxidation state of minus 3 in NH4ClO4 whereas, it has an oxidation state of 0 in N2 molecule in the product side. Here, the oxidation number of nitrogen has increased by 3 via losing 3 electrons. So, Nitrogen here is oxidised.

Hence, all the options are correct.